# Best way to encrypt images in Android

Tags: android, encryption

I have an application in which I download images from a server. I would like to encrypt these images but I don't know what is the best way to do it without losing a lot of performance. My application needs to access like a lot of images at the same time but I need them to be ciphered in order that the user can't get it easily.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: You can set things up so that only your application can request the server for the images .. and any other "web request" will fail due to permissions.  If you are concerned that the images may be "hacked", or  searched by some third party somehow .. then you may need to protect the images.

Comment: https://code.facebook.com/posts/1419122541659395/introducing-conceal-efficient-storage-encryption-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

You might try running your own crypto .. issue, of course, will be how to handle the "key" that you want to use to make sure it is not compromised.  Here is an example of the use of "DES" to encrypt a file.  (You can extend to handle the decryption).

```
public class Obscure {
private byte[] k = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country."
        .getBytes();

public Obscure(String keyString) {
    k = keyString.getBytes();
}

public boolean encryptFile(String source, String target)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    Cipher encoding;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target);

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "DES");
    encoding = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    encoding.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, encoding);
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        cos.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fis.close();
    fos.close();
    cos.close();
    return true;
}
}
```